# How to play a sound upon clicking a button in Windows8 Metro HTML 5 app?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, html5-audio

I have a button and I want to play an audio file upon clicking on the button. Below is the script I am using. But it's not working.Beat.mp3 file is added to my current project.

```
       <audio id="MoreAudio">
             <source src="Beat.mp3"  type="audio/mp3" />
        </audio>
        <input type="button" id="btnMore"  onclick="document.getElementById('MoreAudio').play()" name="More" value="More">
```

Comment: Is Beat.mp3 actually in the base directory of your project, or is it in a subdirectory?

Comment: Try making it an absolute path, e.g. /Beat.mp3

Comment: I have added a folder and updated the src="../Sounds/Beat.mp3".But how do i check if it is still playing that .mp3 file or not using javascript.At any point of time how do i know how much it has played so far ?

Comment: Are you sure you can hear the sound if it was playing?  Can you hear system sounds?